# Which of the given subsets of the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ are connected.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, connectedness

$\mathbb R^3$ is the vector space.The subspace $V$ is spanned by $\{u_1=(1,1,1),u_2=(0,1,1)\}.$ $$u_3=(1,0,1).$$ Then which of the following are correct ?

$1.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{(0,0,0)\}$ is not connected.

$2.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{ tu_1+(1-t)u_2:0\le t\le 1\}$  is connected.

$3.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{ tu_1+tu_3:0\le t\le 1$} is connected.

$4.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{(t,2t,2t):t\in \mathbb R$} is connected.

Now I think $V$ is like $\mathbb R^2$ and $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)$ is not connected.But including the point $0$ makes it connected again. In fact I think all the given sets would be connected.The first set adding $(0,0,0)$ to the set $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)$ and thus connecting it. Now the second and third one each adds a straight line to $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{(0,0,0)\}$ and thus connected. Option $3$ adds to $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{(0,0,0)\}$ anothe connected set which is the continuous image of the set $x=t$ of $\mathbb R$ under the map $f(t)=(t,2t,2t).$ So all are connected sets.

Am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: CSIR NET June question. I suggest thinking in the lines of linear dependence and independence

Comment: By the way, are you sure of $u_1$ and $u_2$, and the spanning vectors of $V$, because its different in the question paper?

Comment: @vidyarthi -.Sir I got this question from a book. Now I don'don't know if they made any mistakes or not.  I don't have the question paper.

Comment: @vidyarthi : But since you said I'I'll try and get the paper from  CSIR site. At the same time I'I'd like to know if my solution for these set of vector s is correct.

Comment: Your solution to first one is not correct as $\mathbb{R}^3/V$ is not a plane because $V$ consists of two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: @vidyarthi : No I said $V$ looks like $\mathbb R^2$ not $\mathbb R^3\backslash V.$ Let me check for typos still.

Comment: @vidyarthi : I thought subtracting a hyperspace would ruin the connectivity of the whole space.

Comment: The question you asked, if from CSIR exam, is wrong. See here, for the right question. The question number is 66-http://csirhrdg.res.in/mathA_June2016.pdf